# using information in a column to create a new column in r

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a data set like this one:

```
record <- c("2000-01-22","2001-01-22","2002-01-22")
brand <- c("blue","red","yellow")
sale <- c("5","42","54")
mydf <- data.frame(record,brand,sale)
mydf

      record  brand sale
1 2000-01-22   blue    5
2 2001-01-22    red   42
3 2002-01-22 yellow   54
```

I would like to create a new column called "year" to include the different years only, such as:

```
   record     brand sale  year
1 2000-01-22   blue    5  2000
2 2001-01-22    red   42  2001
3 2002-01-22 yellow   54  2002
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Baz

Comment: For such a simple question you should post the results of searches and the code you have attempted. Otherwise there will be downvotes for "lack of effort"

Comment: @BondedDust; thanks for your comments. I will do that in my next question. My sincere apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using another package.
How about

```
mydf$year <- as.numeric(substr(mydf$record,1,4))
> mydf
      record  brand sale year
1 2000-01-22   blue    5 2000
2 2001-01-22    red   42 2001
3 2002-01-22 yellow   54 2002
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I came close to the above and probably I would not be able to go all the way. I was using fdata$year <- substr(fdata$test,1,4) and could not get what I wanted. Your help is very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `lubridate::year`:

```
library(lubridate)

mydf$year <- year(as.Date(mydf$record))
> mydf
      record  brand sale year
1 2000-01-22   blue    5 2000
2 2001-01-22    red   42 2001
3 2002-01-22 yellow   54 2002
```

Comment: I am sure that the above will work but I haven't been able to download the lubridate library due to poor internet connection. However, it an alternative that I will use once I have the lubridate library. Many thanks to you!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could be of help :). My advice (I work with time series every day) is to use dates (i.e. Date, POSIXct, POSIXlt) whenever you can. Base R and packages like lubridate, zoo, xts etc offer soo many functions and ways to manipulate dates that you will find much more helpful than having to work with strings or numbers.